# How to keep persistent volumes in sync between clusters?

Tags: wordpress, docker, kubernetes

I'm trying to get an installation of Wordpress running in Kubernetes, as well as have an option of running the same configuration locally in minikube. I want to use the standard Docker image of Wordpress: https://hub.docker.com/_/wordpress/.

I'm having trouble with making sure that the plugins and templates are in sync though. The Docker container exposes a Volume at /var/www/html. Wordpress installation, as well as my plugins will live there.

Assuming I do the development on Minikube, along with the installation of plugins etc. How do handle the move between Persistent Volumes between my local cluster and the target cluster? Should I just reinstall Wordpress every time when the Pod is scaled?

Answer (score 3):

You can follow Writing Portable Configuration (https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#writing-portable-configuration) guide for persistent volume if you are planning to migrate it to different cluster.

Answer (score 0):

In a real production scenario you would want to use a standard tool to backup and migrate persistent volumes between clusters. [Valero](https://velero.io) is such a tool which enables you to achieve that.